# How to use ternary operator on undefined objects

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I am trying to conditionally set a variable with a ternary operator, but am getting the following error:

> Cannot set property 'po_no' of undefined

```
let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shopping-cart'));

console.log(cart); // Evaluates to []

console.log(cart.length); // Evaluates to 0

this.order.po_no = (cart.length > 0) ? cart[0]['order']['po_no'] : "P.O. Number";
```

I'd like a "clean" method to set these variable since there are many in the actual proect.

What would be a good way to conditionally set `po_no`?

Why doesn't the ternary operator skip over `cart[0]` when `cart.length > 0` evaluates to `false`?

Comment: `cart.length` is clearly greater than 0 but `cart[0]['order']` is `undefined`.

Comment: When I log `cart.length` it returns `0`.

Comment: @Matthew I don't believe that. Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: I'm not sure of the context (the rest of your code), but if `cart` were really an empty array you would not get that error (in the code above).

Comment: If cart evaluates to `[]` then `cart[0]` can't be defined.

Comment: Mmm. I found my issue. I was actually trying to assign to `this.order.po_no =`, not `let po_no =` so I was trying to assign to an `undefined` object. I thought defining `this.order` would be sufficient...

Comment: The properties of `this.order` need to be allocated first...

Comment: @Matthew, please close the question or answer yourself.

Comment: @NinaScholz How do I close?

Comment: @Matthew, i don't know. i havn't asked a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to assign to an `undefined` object with the same name as the order key, so was unable to set to `this.order.po_no`.

After instantiating `this.order` properly the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

If cart.length evaluates to 0, there must not be an error "Cannot set property 'po_no' of undefined", however to be safe, try the below code:

```
let po_no = (cart.length > 0 && cart[0]['order']) ? cart[0]['order']['po_no'] : "P.O. Number";
```

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, safe access to po_no would be,

```
let po_no = (cart && cart[0] && cart[0].order && cart[0].order.po_no) 
            || "P.O. Number";
```

Note: This access will also ignore undefined or falsy `po_no`

Comment: I'd personally just go with `cart && cart[0] && cart[0].order && cart[0].order.po_no` - the first expression checking the length is just a bit redundant and doesn't fit the style of the other ones.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I found out that I was trying to assign to an undefined object with the same name. `this.order` was defined, but not `this.order.po_no`.

Comment: Oh that's right, I missed it, it says cannot **set** property of undefined.